What's the best way to calculate the weekday?
I have time series data with a TEXT timestamp formatted as DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss.sss (.sss = ms).
I extract each component from the TEXT timestamp field and compose an ISO formatted timestamp as YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.sss.
I read through the documentation on the strftime function but the following doesn't work:
CREATE TABLE tickdata (
    DateTime TEXT, -- source format = "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss.sss"
    class TEXT,
    category TEXT,
    upper INT,
    lower INT,
    diff INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (upper - lower) STORED,
    gen_year  INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SUBSTRING(DateTime, 7, 4)) STORED,
    gen_month INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SUBSTRING(DateTime, 4, 2)) STORED,
    gen_day   INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SUBSTRING(DateTime, 1, 2)) STORED,
    gen_wkd   INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS CAST(strftime('%w',DateTime) AS INT) STORED, -- syntax error
--  gen_wkd   INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS strftime('%w',DateTime) STORED,       -- also syntax error
--  gen_wkd   CAST(strftime('%w',DateTime) AS INT) GENERATED ALWAYS STORED, -- also syntax error
    gen_hr    INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SUBSTRING(DateTime, 12, 2)) STORED,
    gen_min   INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SUBSTRING(DateTime, 15, 2)) STORED,
    gen_sec   INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SUBSTRING(DateTime, 18, 2)) STORED,
    gen_ms    INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SUBSTRING(DateTime, 21, 3)) STORED,
    gen_ISODate TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
        FORMAT('%04d', gen_year) || '-' ||
        FORMAT('%02d', gen_month) || '-' ||
        FORMAT('%02d', gen_day) || ' ' ||
        FORMAT('%02d', gen_hr) || ':' ||
        FORMAT('%02d', gen_min) || ':' ||
        FORMAT('%02d', gen_sec) || '.' ||
        FORMAT('%03d', gen_ms) -- format = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.sss"
    ) STORED
);

How can I create a calculated column that stores the day of the week that each row timestamp falls into?

The syntax errors happen because the generating function has to be in parentheses, as in INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (strftime...).

As in the comment, you need to wrap parentheses.
Also, you are passing the wrong argument.
gen_wkd INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (strftime('%w', gen_ISODate)) STORED,


The multiple format + concat could just be one call, and judging by explain output may be more efficient that way:
printf('%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d',
       gen_year, gen_month, gen_day,
       gen_hr, gen_min, gen_sec, gen_ms)

(If you mean ISO 8601, shouldn't the space be a T?)

I s'pose you are technically correct in saying the space between date and time should be a T if it is as per ISO 8601...the main thing for me is correct sort ability by the timestamp, so in this case it makes no difference as long as it is consistent. But I take your point...

Can you give the full line syntax for printf('%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%03d',        gen_year, gen_month, gen_day,        gen_hr, gen_min, gen_sec, gen_ms) ?

not sure what you mean. gen_ISODate TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( printf(...) ) STORED ? (I understand printf is now just an alias for format but that seems to have happened after my version (3.37.2) which doesn't know format

Testing shows that this SQL code with printf() works: CREATE TABLE data (DateTime TEXT,g_year INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SUBSTRING(DateTime,7,4)) STORED,g_month INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SUBSTRING(DateTime,4,2)) STORED,g_day INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SUBSTRING(DateTime,1,2)) STORED,g_hr INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SUBSTRING(DateTime,12,2)) STORED,g_min INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SUBSTRING(DateTime,15,2)) STORED,g_sec INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SUBSTRING(DateTime,18,2)) STORED,g_ISODate TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (printf('%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d',g_year,g_month,g_day,g_hr,g_min,g_sec)) STORED);

Thanks - you were right, I was using the wrong input column. The weekday now works, but the period still does not. Will read the dox again...
